# Flutter IOS CocaPods could not find compatible version for pod "Firebase/Messaging"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase, macos

I'm building app for ios for few months.
Everything working fine.
Now I'm getting issue of version not compatible on pod install.

```
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Warning: firebase_app_id_file.json file does not exist. This may cause issues in upload-symbols. If this error is unexpected, try running flutterfire configure again.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Messaging (= 8.11.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Messaging

    firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.9, which depends on
      Firebase/Messaging (= 8.15.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Messaging` inside your development pod `firebase_messaging`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Messaging` to apply changes you've made.
```

I tried pod update,pod repo update.
still getting same error
I tried other solution on stack overflow and github,
But none of that help.
Recently I add firebase analytics in my project.
on podfile.lock deletion i got log:

````
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Warning: firebase_app_id_file.json file does not exist. This may cause issues in upload-symbols. If this error is unexpected, try running flutterfire configure again.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.11.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 12.4 (21F79)
       Xcode : 13.4.1 (13F100)
         Git : git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in versions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:124:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:124:in `block in versions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:479:in `concurrent_requests_catching_errors'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:121:in `versions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:99:in `block in versions_by_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:98:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:98:in `each_with_object'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:98:in `versions_by_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64e%27%29%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
````

My Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

PodFile.Lock :

```
  - barcode_scan2 (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - MTBBarcodeScanner
    - SwiftProtobuf
  - connectivity (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - Reachability
  - device_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - device_info_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (8.11.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 8.11.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (8.11.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 8.11.0)
  - firebase_core (1.13.1):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)
    - Flutter
  - firebase_messaging (10.0.9):
    - Firebase/Messaging (= 8.11.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseCore (8.11.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.11.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (8.11.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - FirebaseMessaging (8.11.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_restart (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - FMDB (2.7.5):
    - FMDB/standard (= 2.7.5)
  - FMDB/standard (2.7.5)
  - geolocator_apple (1.2.0):
    - Flutter
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.1.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.2)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.7.0):
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.7.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.7.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - image_picker (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - MTBBarcodeScanner (5.0.11)
  - nanopb (2.30908.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30908.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30908.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30908.0)
  - otp_autofill (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - package_info_plus (0.4.5):
    - Flutter
  - path_provider_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - "permission_handler (5.1.0+2)":
    - Flutter
  - PromisesObjC (2.0.0)
  - Reachability (3.2)
  - share (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - shared_preferences_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sms_autofill (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sqflite (0.0.2):
    - Flutter
    - FMDB (>= 2.7.5)
  - SwiftProtobuf (1.18.0)
  - syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - telephony (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - url_launcher_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - video_player_avfoundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - wakelock (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - webview_flutter_wkwebview (0.0.1):
    - Flutter

DEPENDENCIES:
  - barcode_scan2 (from `.symlinks/plugins/barcode_scan2/ios`)
  - connectivity (from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`)
  - device_info (from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`)
  - device_info_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios`)
  - Firebase/Messaging
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)
  - flutter_local_notifications (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`)
  - flutter_restart (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_restart/ios`)
  - geolocator_apple (from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`)
  - image_picker (from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`)
  - otp_autofill (from `.symlinks/plugins/otp_autofill/ios`)
  - package_info_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`)
  - path_provider_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`)
  - permission_handler (from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`)
  - share (from `.symlinks/plugins/share/ios`)
  - shared_preferences_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`)
  - sms_autofill (from `.symlinks/plugins/sms_autofill/ios`)
  - sqflite (from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`)
  - syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer (from `.symlinks/plugins/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/ios`)
  - telephony (from `.symlinks/plugins/telephony/ios`)
  - url_launcher_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`)
  - video_player_avfoundation (from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player_avfoundation/ios`)
  - wakelock (from `.symlinks/plugins/wakelock/ios`)
  - webview_flutter_wkwebview (from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - FMDB
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleUtilities
    - MTBBarcodeScanner
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC
    - Reachability
    - SwiftProtobuf

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  barcode_scan2:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/barcode_scan2/ios"
  connectivity:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios"
  device_info:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios"
  device_info_plus:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_messaging:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter
  flutter_local_notifications:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios"
  flutter_restart:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_restart/ios"
  geolocator_apple:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios"
  image_picker:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios"
  otp_autofill:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/otp_autofill/ios"
  package_info_plus:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios"
  path_provider_ios:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios"
  permission_handler:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios"
  share:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/share/ios"
  shared_preferences_ios:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios"
  sms_autofill:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/sms_autofill/ios"
  sqflite:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios"
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/ios"
  telephony:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/telephony/ios"
  url_launcher_ios:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios"
  video_player_avfoundation:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/video_player_avfoundation/ios"
  wakelock:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/wakelock/ios"
  webview_flutter_wkwebview:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  barcode_scan2: 0af2bb63c81b4565aab6cd78278e4c0fa136dbb0
  connectivity: c4130b2985d4ef6fd26f9702e886bd5260681467
  device_info: d7d233b645a32c40dfdc212de5cf646ca482f175
  device_info_plus: e5c5da33f982a436e103237c0c85f9031142abed
  Firebase: 44dd9724c84df18b486639e874f31436eaa9a20c
  firebase_core: 08f6a85f62060111de5e98d6a214810d11365de9
  firebase_messaging: c6608162e71bcfd78198a81eac9c2fa27fed3aae
  FirebaseCore: 2f4f85b453cc8fea4bb2b37e370007d2bcafe3f0
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 64d9709d804a6c25bd77841371c1fcfd909d5601
  FirebaseInstallations: 044eede8a049bce71c4541ee68d6e4364fcbe774
  FirebaseMessaging: 02e248e8997f71fa8cc9d78e9d49ec1a701ba14a
  Flutter: 50d75fe2f02b26cc09d224853bb45737f8b3214a
  flutter_local_notifications: 0c0b1ae97e741e1521e4c1629a459d04b9aec743
  flutter_restart: 11eea2413f4947979cf19e99e9347ca021071157
  FMDB: 2ce00b547f966261cd18927a3ddb07cb6f3db82a
  geolocator_apple: b741765c55dc21950e3e106e8b3584e55cf81ce5
  GoogleDataTransport: 629c20a4d363167143f30ea78320d5a7eb8bd940
  GoogleUtilities: e0913149f6b0625b553d70dae12b49fc62914fd1
  image_picker: 541dcbb3b9cf32d87eacbd957845d8651d6c62c3
  MTBBarcodeScanner: f453b33c4b7dfe545d8c6484ed744d55671788cb
  nanopb: a0ba3315591a9ae0a16a309ee504766e90db0c96
  otp_autofill: 93bcc21475705d35445927cb9aef24e818bbf083
  package_info_plus: 6c92f08e1f853dc01228d6f553146438dafcd14e
  path_provider_ios: 14f3d2fd28c4fdb42f44e0f751d12861c43cee02
  permission_handler: ccb20a9fad0ee9b1314a52b70b76b473c5f8dab0
  PromisesObjC: 68159ce6952d93e17b2dfe273b8c40907db5ba58
  Reachability: 33e18b67625424e47b6cde6d202dce689ad7af96
  share: 0b2c3e82132f5888bccca3351c504d0003b3b410
  shared_preferences_ios: 548a61f8053b9b8a49ac19c1ffbc8b92c50d68ad
  sms_autofill: c461043483362c3f1709ee76eaae6eb570b31686
  sqflite: 6d358c025f5b867b29ed92fc697fd34924e11904
  SwiftProtobuf: c3c12645230d9b09c72267e0de89468c5543bd86
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: bb9998884b864cfedf72628df3503bdf57e397c0
  telephony: c41768fae9fb5495781b05a72004106ca33ec777
  url_launcher_ios: 839c58cdb4279282219f5e248c3321761ff3c4de
  video_player_avfoundation: e489aac24ef5cf7af82702979ed16f2a5ef84cff
  wakelock: d0fc7c864128eac40eba1617cb5264d9c940b46f
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: 005fbd90c888a42c5690919a1527ecc6649e1162

PODFILE CHECKSUM: ad40df2a9e964a0acd256ae691c998d63e85e2dd

COCOAPODS: 1.11.2
```

What should I do?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try pod repo update or with `pod install --repo-update`.

Comment: I tried all things. Nothing work.

Comment: Can you try removing podfile.lock and try pod install again

Comment: I updated log on removing podfile.lock.

Comment: Please use command `pod deintegrate` and the `pod install`

Comment: What is your deployment target ios platform version in your podfile?

Comment: already did pod deintegrate and pod install

Comment: how can i check deployment target ios platform version

Comment: Share your Podfile and Podfile.lock.

Comment: Ok. Updated in my question.